Is webhook structure should be REST-API?
I have a webhook Server that get a requests from graph-api of whatsapp api, and all the incoming requests have only one route without any specification routeing. I looking  for the best practices to menage and route the incoming requests.
For now, i build a middleware that change the req.url according to that body object, then next to the express router, is it good?

Its not common to ask yes/no questions here. Ask specific questions to a problem and share some code examples to describe the problem.
